# In CakePHP how can you manually set the ORM table and entity or model backing the Form Helper?

Tags: cakephp

I have a database table called 'items'.  CakePhP 3.0 nicely sets up my 'ItemsController' for me.  But what if I have another, arbitrarily named, class that wants to access my 'items' table.  Call it my 'FooBarController'.  In my method in class FooBarController I've added the:

```
$this->loadModel('Items');
```

`$this->Items` is correctly setup, but the `$this->Form` does not seem to be backed by the 'items' table.  I.e. `loadModel('Items')` correctly sets up `$this->Items` but does not setup the `$this->Form` to be backed by Items.  How can I manually set up `$this->Form` to be backed by Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Upon creating a form

As shown in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#starting-a-form), the form expects a model object as the first parameter:

> Starting a Form
> `Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::create(mixed $model = null, array $options =[])`

So, to create a form using Item fields, pass an instance of an item.  Put the following line into your .ctp file instead of the HTML  statement

```
echo $this->Form->create($anItem);
```

If you don't yet have one, create one.